# Asp.Net Core - Error cannot execute binary file on published (Ubuntu 14.04) web application with supervisor

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here it is: I created an ASP.NET Core web application, and copied all the files on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I can compile and run without a problem, but now I want this application/web site to run permanently.

I followed all the steps described here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html, installed nginx as reverse proxy to run with apache, and all of this run perfectly well.

BUT, trying to use supervisor and start the app from it, I systematically get an error `/usr/bin/dotnet cannot execute binary file`. But, if I move to be in the directory where the application is published, and manually type `dotnet appname.dll` it does start without a glitch.

I am not sure where to look to get this to work with supervisor. Thanks for your help (and if this question should be somewhere else, let me know)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem,  replacing the equivalent of the line `command=bash /usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/HelloMVC/HelloMVC.dll` as described in https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html under "**Configuring Supervisor**" by a little script, far from perfect as I get a  `Warning: HOME environment variable not set.`

Anyway, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/aspnetcore/foesuivi/
dotnet FoESuivi.dll
cd $HOME
```

As a windows programmer, I don't know much about bash scripting, but I certainly can see that I would need to give a value to $HOME before the cd command.

Anyway, after doing a chmod +x to the sh file, and replacing the command= with the full name of the sh file, it is now working, I can reboot and my site is immediately available.